# How to Clear SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, msbi

I got this error message after running my SSIS package.

Source : flat text file
Target : sql database

> Warning: 0x80019002 at Package: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (3) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
> SSIS package "........\Package.dtsx" finished: Failure.
> The program '[7312] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Below is my simple source file

```
CAS, SubName, ListCode, Type, CountryCode, ListName
^1000413-72-8^,^fasiglifam^,^447^,^Chemical Inventory^,^EU^,^ECICS Custom Tariff Codes^
^1000413-72-8^,^fasiglifam^,^0^,^^,^NN^,^SPHERA Global Substance List^
```

Below SSIS flow task failing in source. Target is SQL database.

[image]

Please help me on this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of error means some issue is there and you need to fix it. But, still if you want to set the number to higher value, you can set at the package level.

[image: Property for changing Maximum Error Count]